# Sum over the primes of $\frac{\ln(p)}{p^2}$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

$$\sum^{\infty}_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac{\ln(p)}{p^2}$$
I've been able to prove the sum converges ($P(2)<S<\sum^{\infty}_0 \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$  where $P$ is the prime zeta function).
I've been trying to solve it by replacing 2 with $s$ and integrating.
$$\int^\infty_s\sum^{\infty}_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac{\ln(p)}{p^k}dk=\sum^{\infty}_{p\in \mathbb P}\int^\infty_s \frac{\ln(p)}{p^k}dk=\sum^\infty_{p\in \mathbb P} \frac{1}{p^s}$$
but I'm unsure how to continue and I am pretty sure undoing the integral will be rather hard.
Can any of you help?

Comment: Don't expect a closed form for this, but you can numiercally evaluate such sum quite precisely https://oeis.org/A136271

Answer (score 1):

$\sum \limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{\ln p}{p^2}  \leq  \sum \limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{\sqrt {p}}{p^2}$ since $ \ln x  \leq \sqrt{x} $ for all $x>0$ and we want to prove that $ \sum \limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{\sqrt {p}}{p^2}$ converge !

$\sum \limits_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{\sqrt {p}}{p^2} \leq \sum \limits_{2\leq j \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{j \sqrt{j}}$ since $ \frac{1}{j \sqrt{j}}$ is monotone function then $  \frac{1}{j \sqrt{j}} \leq \int \limits_{j-1}^{j} \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x}} $

And so $\sum \limits_{2\leq j \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{j \sqrt{j}} \leq \sum \limits_{2\leq j \in \mathbb{N}} \int \limits_{j-1}^{j} \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{x}} = \int \limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx} {x \sqrt{x}}  = 2$

The approach you took is harder because its more accurate and in general used when we want to calculate something like $ \sum \limits_{p > x} \frac{\ln p}{p^2}$ (as function related to $x$) and not just to check convergence though you can do it.